# Advanced search using enumerateChildNodesWithName method

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, enumeration, sknode

I am having ten sprites (A0,A2...A9  sprites) and I am enumerating their parent (`myNode`) using next search string `A[0-9]` in order to match sprites named A0, A1...A9.

From the docs about using this *pattern* as search string :

> This search string matches any of the current node’s children that are
>   named A0, A1, …, A9.

Here is the code I use:

```
myNode.enumerateChildNodesWithName("A[0-9]") { sprite, stop in

     //do some stuff here    
}
```

And this works, like stated in docs. But, let say I have now 20 sprites... When I tried to match sprites named A1, A2, A3...A20, like this:

```
myNode.enumerateChildNodesWithName("A[0-20]") {...}
```

it didn't worked... Am I expecting too much of this feature or I am missing something ?

I am able to match desired sprites in a few different ways, for example, by putting them in the same container and enumerating all of the sprites in it, but that is not the point, and I am wondering if there is something that can be done in order to use `[lowerBound-upperBound]` notation ?

Comment: I guess it's more or less regex notation, rather than lower/upper bound

Comment: I don't think [0-9] is "lower-bound-upperBound", but rather just "A single character from 0-9". Not sure how advanced the search can be,

Comment: Could you rename your sprites to A01-A20 and try A[0-2][1-9] ?

Comment: @SteveIves Tried something similar, but I can try that as well... Documentation is not detailed about this particular example of [advanced search](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/) And yeah, it doesn't seems that advanced. It is not clear if this some sort of regex, like zcui93 said (and if it is, how to use it). Or if it isn't, then again, how to use it (and what are possibilities)...

Comment: The documentation is definitely lacking - I remember your answer to my question (//. to search EVERY node in the scene, which worked but isn't logical from the description)

Comment: @SteveIves Okay, that worked (naming nodes A01, rather than A1). You can make your answer. Thanks a bunch :) Also if you have any idea how to match nodes named A1, A2, A3... and matching them all together with nodes named A23, A24, please post that too...That would be a plus. Still, this is acceptable for me as well.

Comment: You're welcome - just learned something myself too, as I didn't have a suitable project to test it on :-)

Comment: @Whirlwind - it looks like it might actually be a regex. Try ^A[0-9]{1,2}$ which should match a string consisting of an A followed by 1 or 2 of the digits 0-9. I just tested it with the full search name "//.^A[0-9]{1,2}$" and it appeared to work.

Comment: @SteveIves Oh cool , so it is regex actually! I tried it and it works! Nice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name your sprites `A01-A20` and try `A[0-2][1-9]`

Edit: It appears that the search argument is actually a regex. From the declaration of the function:

> name An Xpath style path that can include simple regular expressions
>   for matching node names.

So ^A[0-9]{1,2}$ will match 'A' followed by one or 2 digits as the complete node name.